# How to properly filter an object that has an array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to filter an array to get only what I want and I have tried with filter and reduce, but I was not able to make it fully work. I'm trying to get only the objects that has `"System.State"` with an `"oldValue"` and a `"newValue"`

```
const data = {
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 23,
      "fields": {
        "System.State": {
          "oldValue": "Forecasted",
          "newValue": "Done"
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

The problem is that `value` array contains several objects that may NOT have `"System.State"` and some that have `"System.State"` but only with `"newValue"`, instead of `"oldValue"` and `"newValue"`, so I'm receiving a lot of undefined errors and I really don't know how to treat these situations.

This is a example that dont have `"System.State"` and another one that have `"System.State`" but with `"newValue"` only:

```
const data = {
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 23,
      "fields": {
        "System.State": {
          "oldValue": "Forecasted",
          "newValue": "Done"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "fields": {
        "System.State": {
          "newValue": "New"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "fields": {
        "System.AuthorizedDate": { // This is only an example of an object that does not have System.State
          "newValue": "2020-03-13T14:14:37.1Z"
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

I'm using TFS API if anyone wants to know. This is what I have tried using filter:

```
data.value.fields.filter(status => status.fields['System.State'].oldValue === 'Forecasted' && status.fields['System.State'] === 'Done')
```

And this was using reducer:

```
  const filter = data.value.reduce((c, n) => {
    const HasNewAndOldValue = c.fields['System.State'].oldValue === 'Forecasted' && c.fields['System.State'].newValue === 'Done';
    if (c.fields['System.State'] && HasNewAndOldValue) {
      return c;
    }
    c.push(n); 
  }, [])
  console.log(data.value.fields && filter);
```

What I'm doing wrong? Btw, I'm using `['System.State']` because I can't access an object property that has a dot.

Comment: This `data.value.fields` is undefined, did check the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `filter` example, replace `data.value.fields.filter()` with `data.value.filter()`, because `data.value` is an array.

```js
const data = {
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 23,
      "fields": {
        "System.State": {
          "oldValue": "Forecasted",
          "newValue": "Done"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "fields": {
        "System.State": {
          "newValue": "New"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "fields": {
        "System.AuthorizedDate": { // This is only an example of an object that does not have System.State
          "newValue": "2020-03-13T14:14:37.1Z"
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}

console.log(
  data.value.filter((item) => {
    const fields = item.fields || {};
    const state = fields['System.State'];
    if (!state) {
      return false;
    }

    return state.oldValue && state.newValue;
  })

);
```

Comment: Note that this will not work if  `oldValue` or `newValue` is present but falsey, such as `0` or `null`. Otherwise, this appears to be the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works in my case. Since you answered first, I will accept your answer. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This `data.value.fields` is undefined, you should access the property `fields` through each object within the property `value`.

```js
const data = {  "value": [    {      "id": 23,      "fields": {        "System.State": {          "oldValue": "Forecasted",          "newValue": "Done"        }      }    },    {      "id": 24,      "fields": {        "System.State": {          "newValue": "New"        }      }    },    {      "id": 25,      "fields": {        "System.AuthorizedDate": {          "newValue": "2020-03-13T14:14:37.1Z"        }      }    }  ]};

console.log(data.value.filter(({fields: {"System.State": state}}) => {
  return state && state.oldValue === "Forecasted" && state.newValue === "Done";
}));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution and it works just fine but since Typing answered first, I had to accept his answer.

Comment: @ncesar yw and don't worry!

Answer (score 1):

Just filter the `value` property to include only the array elements that contain:

```js
"fields": {
  "System.State": {
    "oldValue": "anything",
    "newValue:": "anything"
  }
}
```

```js
function filterData(data) {
  let filteredValue = data.value.filter(el => {
    return el.fields["System.State"] &&
      el.fields["System.State"].oldValue &&
      el.fields["System.State"].newValue;
  });
  return { value: filteredValue };
}

const data = {
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 23,
      "fields": {
        "System.State": {
          "oldValue": "Forecasted",
          "newValue": "Done"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "fields": {
        "System.State": {
          "newValue": "New"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "fields": {
        "System.AuthorizedDate": {
        // This is only an example of an object that does not have System.State
          "newValue": "2020-03-13T14:14:37.1Z"
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}

let filtData = filterData(data);
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
  JSON.stringify(filtData, null, 2);
```

```html
Filtered data:<br/>
<pre id="results"></pre>
```